# Macro disabled in excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

[image]

I have a macro workbook with some macro inside. I already "enable all the macros" in the trust center as shown in the screenshot above but I'm still not able to run the macro successfully. I tried to search on google but couldn't find any solution that is able to fix my problem. Any advise or help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's not enough information here to give any kind of useful answer.

Comment: what is the information needed?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Is the actually in the XLSM file? How is it called? What does "I'm still not able to run the macro successfully" mean exactly? Do you get an error message?

Comment: "disable all macros with Notification" is the setting you want - that last one offers you no security against running unwanted code.

Comment: The code is actually use to duplicate the sheet, I think the code is working well as all my staffs are able to run the macro in their device except me. Yes, it is XLSM file. The error that I get is `Cannot run the macro. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled`

Comment: @Tim, I want to run the macro, but I couldn't, so I tried to enable all macro, if I disable all the macros, then I would not be able to run the macro right?

Comment: "disable all macros with Notification" means Excel will prompt you and ask if you want to run code in a workbook - if you use the last option then all code runs automatically without any input from you.  That's dangerous when opening workbooks you don't control.

Comment: What @TimWilliams said *"disable all macros with Notification"* is the option you want and read [Macros in Office files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6) for how to activate them. • Make sure you close Excel after switching the macro options. If that does not work restart your computer (just to ensure nothing odd is going on).

Comment: What exactly do you do to trigger that message about macros being disabled? Just open the file?  Or something else?

Comment: I have a macro button, once I click the button, it will trigger the macro to run. But the error shown when i click the button. So i tried to `Enable all macros` in the setting although i know it is dangerous to do so but I just want to test whether it will work or not, but unfortunately it is still showing me the error that i mentioned above

Comment: You may have to unblock the workbook in Windows. Browse to the file in Windows File Explorer, right-click on it, choose Properties, and at the bottom of the dialog, check the Unblock box, then click OK.

Comment: It's possible your button is trying to call a macro in a different workbook.  Check the button to make sure.